# Publish prerelease (alpha) version using VSTS

Tags: nuget, azure-devops

I try to pack and publish a package as prelease on VSTS.

In the build step: dotnet (2* preview) pack I set a custom build number:

Automatic package versioning: use the build number.

Options:

```
$(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Year:yyyy).$(Month).$(DayOfMonth)$(Rev:.r)-alpha
```

It seems to build correctly:

> Build #aspcore-repository (sqlserver)_2018.1.29.5-alpha has been
>   queued.

But in the pack step it loses the -alpha in the version and it is not published as a prelease package:

```
[command]"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" pack
   d:\a\1\s\SqlServer\Citolab.Repository.SqlServer.csproj --output
   d:\a\1\a /p:PackageVersion=2018.1.29.3 --verbosity Detailed
```

What should I do to publish the package as prelease version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug/feature of using the BuildNumber as your version source. [I've submitted a pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/pull/6137), but it hasn't been taken into the Nuget tasks yet. as a workaround use **Environment Variable** instead of Build Number and set the value to: `BUILD_BUILDNUMBER`.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'm close now. I get this error now: 'Citolab.Repository.SqlServer_2018.1.29.1-alpha' is not a valid version string. Think the underscore between SqlServer and 2018 should be a dot. Any idea how I can change this?

Comment: Use my vsts variable tasks to strip everything up to the `version-alpha`. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jessehouwing.jessehouwing-vsts-variable-tasks

Comment: Build number by default searches for 0.0.0.0 and captures that. The other options just take the complete value and don't perform a search.

Comment: I tried things with your variable task, but I don't get it. As I understand your task create a new variable based on a existing. But it seems like dotnet pack is just concatenating two variables with an underscore.

Comment: My task can be used to remove the build definition name using search & replace. You can assign that to a new variable in order to feed that to the pack task.

Comment: Tried a lot of things, probably doing something stupid. My last try: $(BUILD_BUILDNUMBER) = Citolab.Repository.SqlServer_2018.1.30.2-alpha search: .+?(?=_)_ replacement: Citolab.Repository.SqlServer. result: error : 'Citolab.Repository.SqlServer.BUILDNUMBER)' is not a valid version string. Does exactly what I want, except it takes $(BUILD_BUILDNUMBER) as string instead it resolves. I

Comment: Replace $(Build.DefinitionName)_ with an emptyvstring

Comment: Tried that as well but that results in: : '$(BUILD_BUILDNUMBER)' is not a valid version string. Or if I replace with 'Citolab.Repository.SqlServer.': 'Citolab.Repository.SqlServer.$(BUILD_BUILDNUMBER)' is not a valid version string.